# Convert column of data to a delimited list in a single cell

Tags: excel

Is there an "easy" way to take data like this

```
Part#   Attr1       Attr2   Attr3
101     2.50"       8.00"   225 lbs
101     2.50"       8.00"   275 lbs
```

**Notice the same part# has two rows, with the difference being Attr3**

And turn it into a single row with the unique values being separated by a ;

```
Part#   Attr1       Attr2   Attr3
101     2.50"       8.00"   225 lbs;275 lbs
```

My data is over 100,000 rows so I'm looking for a formula (or plugin) that can do it all quickly.

NOTE: my version of Excel does not have TEXTJOIN

Comment: If you have office 365 then you can use UNIQUE to get the unique list of part# then use TEXTJOIN in the other 3 columns to concatenate the attributes.

Comment: @ScottCraner TEXTJOIN is not a formula on my version :(

Comment: Then this will take vba.

Comment: Is attribute 3 the only column that causes additional rows per part#?

Comment: @Isolated no, it could be Attr1, 2 or 3

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365.

- Unpivot the attribute columns
- Remove the duplicates
- Pivot on the attribute columns

  - You need to edit the M-Code in order to do a text aggregation, as that is not built-in to the UI

**M-Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Part#", Int64.Type}, {"Attr1", type text}, {"Attr2", type text}, {"Attr3", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Part#"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Unpivoted Other Columns"),

    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Duplicates", 
        List.Distinct(#"Removed Duplicates"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value",

            //custom text aggregation function
            each List.Accumulate(_,"",(state, current) => if state = "" then current 
                else state & "; " & current ))
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]

*Note: If you require the concatenated values to be sorted, you can add a sorting function to the text aggregation function. Simplest would look like:*

```
each List.Accumulate(List.Sort(_),"",(state, current) => if state = "" then current 
                else state & "; " & current ))
```